# Intersection of two data table return zero rows with custom Data Comparer

Tags: c#, .net, datarow

I want to get all common rows (including duplicate rows) between two data table having more than 45000 rows.

However, I want to skip "Column 2" and "all columns after column 6" out of comparison scope.But I am getting no rows as intersection result. Could any one suggest me where I am doing wrong?

Here's my code written:

```
CustomDataRowComparer myDRComparer = new CustomDataRowComparer();
var commonData = outputTable.AsEnumerable().Intersect(prevTable.AsEnumerable(), myDRComparer).CopyToDataTable();



   public class CustomDataRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
    {
        public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {


                if (i !=1) // Don't want to consider this column for comparison
                {
                    if (x[i].ToString() != y[i].ToString())
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            }
            return true;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
        {
            return obj.ToString().GetHashCode();
        }
```

Comment: I think the hash is wrong.  Try this : return string.Join("^",obj.ItemArray.Select((x,i) => i == 1 ? "" : x.ToString()).ToArray()).GetHashCode();

Comment: I just realized if you use my hash the Equals() method can just compare DataRow x to DataRow y the hash will be unique and will determine where rows match.

Answer (score 1):

Here is full code

```
    public class CustomDataRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
    {
        public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
        {
            return x.Equals(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
        {
            return string.Join("^", obj.ItemArray.Select((x, i) => i == 1 ? "" : x.ToString()).ToArray()).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I adapt lambda expression to exclude two more columns? Right now, You are excluding i=1. Can we adapt it to exclude i>=7 ?

Comment: I adjusted my data table so that I have 6 columns in beginning that I would like to consider for comparison and I changed the return statement as 'return string.Join("^", obj.ItemArray.Select((x, i) =>i>5? "" : x.ToString()).ToArray()).GetHashCode();' But it's not working still.

Comment: Are you getting back any rows that compare?  Try comparing the same datatable table against itself to see if the code works.  All rows should be returned.

Comment: If I compare same data table, it works fine and return all rows. But it's not working when I am comparing it to another table.It return zero row. However, another table has equal rows if we ignore column 2 value and columns values after column 6.

Comment: Try : (i == 1) || (i >= 5) ?

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. Except I had to change equals function.  public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if ((i == 4) || (i == 5))
                {
                    //ignore
                }
                else
                {
                    if (x[i].ToString() != y[i].ToString())
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

Comment: The code should work by making the equivalent changes in the HashCode.  Not sure why you are only checking 6 rows of the DataTable.